# PowerPoint Add-in Write on Slide in Slideshow

Tags: c#, windows, vsto, add-in

While writing a PowerPoint add-in, I need to draw something on the screen on top of the slideshow.
I am able to draw lines and images, but they disappear almost immediately.

Example code:

```
private void Application_SlideShowBegin(PowerPoint.SlideShowWindow Wn)
{
    using (var g = Graphics.FromHwnd((IntPtr)Wn.HWND))
    {
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 10), new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100), new System.Drawing.Point(200, 300));
        Image img = Properties.Resources.img;
        g.DrawImageUnscaled(img, new Rectangle(250, 250, img.Width, img.Height));
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can keep the drawn lines / images on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have seen it earlier - this is about refreshes. The code needs to be run a bit later, so if the paint is delayed, the drawing stays on the window.
The following example now works as expected:

```
private Timer _Ticker = new Timer();
private PowerPoint.SlideShowWindow _SlideshowWindow = null;

private void Application_SlideShowBegin(PowerPoint.SlideShowWindow Wn)
{
    _SlideshowWindow = Wn;
    _Ticker.Interval = 30;
    _Ticker.AutoReset = true;
    _Ticker.Elapsed += Ticker_Elapsed;
    _Ticker.Enabled = true;
}

    private void Ticker_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_Ticker.Enabled)
        {
            using (var g = Graphics.FromHwnd((IntPtr)_SlideshowWindow.HWND))
            {
                g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 10), new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100), new System.Drawing.Point(200, 300));
                Image img = Properties.Resources.img;
                g.DrawImageUnscaled(img, new Rectangle(250, 250, img.Width, img.Height));
            }
            _Ticker.Enabled = false;
            _Ticker.Elapsed -= Ticker_Elapsed;
        }
    }
```